# RxJS retry() semantics

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Given this [example](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html#retrying-sequences) for `.retry()`:

```
// Try three times to get the data and then give up
var source = get('url').retry(3);
```

What does `get()` return? Can someone provide an implementation to make the example work? i.e. to actually retry some asynchronous code 3 times.

I'm just starting out with RxJS, and am trying to understand the semantics, and getting an example of the above would really help, thanks!

Comment: Do u want repeat observable 3 times? If yes, try it var source = Rx.Observable.repeat(null, 3).concatMap(x => Rx.Observable.just(42).delay(1000))

Comment: @xgrommx, it's from your book, right? ;-) I'm trying to do a retry, i.e. if there is an `Error` thrown in `get()`, I want to retry 3 times. I'm not sure how to write the `get()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get` returns an `Observable`. What `retry` does is it subscribes to the underlying `Observable` and captures an `onError` call and then resubscribes to the `Observable` while hiding the `onError` from downstream thus keeping the stream from terminating. Only requirement for the `Observable` is that it must "start on subscribe" semantics or in other words is a cold `Observable`.

So `get` could be implemented as:

```
function get() {
  var count = 0;
  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    if (++count < 2) observer.onError(new Error());
    else {
      observer.onNext("Yay!");
      observer.onCompleted();
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit**

I re-read your question and think I misunderstood what you were asking. The first example I gave is just a quick way of seeing how to make a trivial `Observable` that will work with `retry`. In the scenario that is given of `get` it is doing some sort of http request.

The following is using the [RxJS-DOM Library](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/tree/master/examples) to do the Ajax request but you could use other libraries that have `Promises` as well.

```
//With RxJS DOM
function get(url) {
  return Rx.DOM.ajax({url : url});
} 

//With JQuery Promises
function get(url) {
  return Rx.Observable.defer(function() {
    return $.ajax(url);
  });
}
```

In both cases you are hitting some remote server resource which could potentially error. Adding a `retry` after it would make sure that the issue is not a transient network issue.

Comment: Why not use http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/while.html. In my case which I provide above I use a pure approach =)

Comment: @xgrommx it is really irrelevant what method he uses, you could also use defer + fromPromise if you really wanted, my understanding was the OP just wanted an example of what `get` should return for `retry` to work.

Comment: Thanks @paulpdaniels, exactly what I needed to get me over this speed bump. Both examples are really handy.